# Javascript very simle function returns weird values

Tags: javascript, function

I have the folowing code:

```
<a href="javascript:Add(23905762501722146)">Click</a>

function Add(id) {

    alert(id);

}
```

The value in the alert is 23905762501722144 (-2) from the original value.

Why does this happen?

https://jsfiddle.net/wvtqostd/4/

Comment: Tip: Use as string `Add("23905762501722146")` if you can(not to use for numerical operations).

Comment: Because `23905762501722146` is larger than what JS can represent precisely as integer.

Comment: In Javascript, all numbers are floating numbers and are prone to floating point approximation.

    // This holds true
    10000000000000000 === 10000000000000001

Avoid numbers when approximation is not permitted. If you need to manipulate big integers in Javascript use a library for that.

http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/

https://github.com/substack/node-bigint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log2(23905762501722146) ~= 54.408

JavaScript stores all numbers - including integers - as double precision floats. Double precision mantissa/significand contains 52 bits of information, so some information gets lost storing so long/precise number as you have.

Answer (score 4):

Because 23905762501722144 is to big to represent as integer value... try sending it as string value.